# (Unity) error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float, float)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner Unity programmer, can anyone help I wanted to make an animation for my character, transition from idle to run and jump, but I got this error:

> error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float, float)'

```cs
public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public int score;
    public Text scoreText;
    public int jumpsAmount;
    int jumpsLeft;
    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
    private Vector2 movement;
    Animator animator;
    bool isGrounded;
    float moveInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    float scaleX;

    void Start ( )
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ( );
        scaleX = transform.localScale.x;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ( );
    }

    void Update ( )
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw ( "Horizontal" );
        Jump ( );

        movement = new Vector2 ( moveInput );
        if ( animator )
        {
            animator.SetBool ( "Run", Mathf.Abs ( moveInput ) >= 0.1f );
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate ( )
    {
        Move ( );
    }

    public void Move ( )
    {
        Flip ( );
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 ( moveInput * moveSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y );
    }

    public void Flip ( )
    {
        if ( moveInput > 0 )
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 ( scaleX, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z );
        }
        if ( moveInput < 0 )
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 ( ( -1 ) * scaleX, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z );
        }
    }

    public void Jump ( )
    {
        if ( animator )
        {
            animator.SetTrigger ( "Jump" );
        }

        if ( Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.Space ) )
        {
            CheckIfGrounded ( );
            if ( jumpsLeft > 0 )
            {
                rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 ( rb2d.velocity.x, jumpForce );
                jumpsLeft--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void CheckIfGrounded ( )
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle ( GroundCheck.position, GroundCheck.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ( ).radius, GroundLayer );
        ResetJumps ( );
    }

    public void ResetJumps ( )
    {
        if ( isGrounded )
        {
            jumpsLeft = jumpsAmount;
        }
    }

    public void AddCoin ( int count )
    {
        score += count;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString ( );
    }
}
```

I changed the code in different ways, the error could not be fixed.

Comment: this line `movement = new Vector2 (moveInput);` you have to pass the second parameter as well

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in the error message?

Comment: You never use `movement` anyway .. so what is it good for?

Answer (score 0):

Just like vivek nuna said, you need to have a second parameter also. Write this instead: movement = new Vector2(moveInput, 0). I wonder what you need for this certain variable. Considering that it is private, it won't be accessed by other scripts but you already have some code that deals with moving.